# Katalon Studio - After Click on element - its passed but nothing happened

Tags: selenium, xpath, katalon-studio

When I clicked on the button (after clicking manually, new popup window will open) but in Katalon Studio, when I click, its passed, but nothing happened, window will not open)

Code trials:

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/POkus3/Page_Dashboard - altFINS/vaadin-tab_Overview'))
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/POkus3/Page_Dashboard - altFINS/vaadin-menu-bar_Free Registered User_userMe_6d88ae'))
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/POkus3/Page_Dashboard - altFINS/vaadin-context-menu-item_Accounts'))
WebUI.waitForElementClickable(findTestObject('Pokus2/Page_Accounts - altFINS/Sergej'), 10)
WebUI.doubleClick(findTestObject('Pokus2/Page_Accounts - altFINS/Sergej'))
```

Comment: Do you want to click or doubleclick the button?

Comment: Only Click (I tried with double-click but nothing happened as well) Button where I clicked is in shadow root.

Comment: It sounds like the issue you're facing is two-fold, and that I have handled but one part of it...

It seems like you need to switch to some `<iframe>` or something, before even trying to interact with the button....

Comment: https://docs.katalon.com/docs/author/test-objects/web-test-objects/automation-testing-of-shadow-dom-elements-with-katalon-studio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

Create some custom Keyword class, defined to be:

```
public final class GeneralWebUIUtils { 

    public static int GetNumberOfWindows() { 
        return DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
            .getWindowHandles()
            .size();
    }

    public static boolean WaitForCondition(Closure<Boolean> onCheckCondition, int timeOut, Closure<String> onErrorMessage, FailureHandling failureHandling = FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE) { 
        boolean isConditionSatisfied = false;
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while((!isConditionSatisfied) && (System.currentTimeMillis() <= startTime + timeOut * 1000) { 
            isConditionSatisfied = onCheckCondition();
        }

        if ((!isConditionSatisfied) && failureHandling.equals(FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE))
            throw new StepFailedException(onErrorMessage(this.GetElapsedTime(startTime)));

        return isConditionSatisfied;

    }

    public static boolean WaitForWindowOpenChange(int timeOut, FailureHandling failureHandling = FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE) { 
        final int initNumberOfWindows = this.GetNumberOfWindows();

        return this.WaitForCondition({
                return this.GetNumberOfWindows() != initNumberOfWindows;
            }, 
            timeOut,
            { double elapsedTime ->
                return "Number of open windows/tabs has NOT changed after ${elapsedTime} seconds";
            },
            failureHandling,
        );
    }

    public static double GetElapsedTime(long startTimeMillis) { 
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis) / 1000.0;
    }
}
```

and then, in your test case, call it like this:

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject('Pokus2/Page_Accounts - altFINS/Sergej'));
GeneralWebUIUtils.WaitForWindowOpenChange(15);
```

This will solve your problem, if not just fail your test case at the very least.

Please review the code, and let me know if you have any questions!

**UPDATE**: I just saw, from your comment, that the input button you are trying to interact with, exists within some shadow root.

In that case, you need to [create Test Object for the shadow root element, and then make the Test Object for it a child Test Object of that](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/author/test-objects/web-test-objects/automation-testing-of-shadow-dom-elements-with-katalon-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Recently faced a similar issue for Android devices.

But clicking the same element twice *(not a double click,but single-clicking twice)* helped me.